# How do I convert a regular expression in a valid .NET format to valid Java format?

Tags: java, .net, regex

I want to use the following regular expression which is written within a C# .NET code, in a Java code, but I can't seem to convert it right, can you help me out?

```
Regex(@"\w+:\/\/(?<Domain>[\x21-\x22\x24-\x2E\x30-\x3A\x40-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A]+)(?<Relative>/?\S*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct translation would be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
  "\\w+://([\\x21-\\x22\\x24-\\x2E\\x30-\\x3A\\x40-\\x5A\\x5F\\x61-\\x7A]+)(/?\\S*)",
  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Java has no equivalent for C#'s verbatim strings, so you always have to escape backslashes.  And Java's regexes don't support named groups, so I converted those to simple capturing groups (named groups are due to be added in Java 7).

But there are a few problems with the original regex:

- The `RegexOptions.Compiled` modifier doesn't do what you probably think it does.  Specifically, it's not related to Java's `compile()` method; that's just a factory method, roughly equivalent to C#'s `new Regex()` constructor.  The `Compiled` modifier causes the regex to be compiled *to CIL bytecode*, which can make it match a lot faster, but at a considerable cost in upfront processing and memory use--and that memory never gets garbage-collected.  If you don't use the regex a lot, the `Compiled` option is probably doing more harm than good, performance-wise.
- The `IgnoreCase/CASE_INSENSITIVE` modifier is pointless since your regex always matches both upper- and lowercase variants wherever it matches letters.
- The `Singleline/DOTALL` modifier is pointless since you never use the dot metacharacter.
- In .NET regexes, the character-class shorthand `\w` is Unicode-aware, equivalent to `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]`.  In Java it's ASCII-only -- `[A-Za-z0-9_]`-- which seems to be more in line with the way you're using it (you could "dumb it down" in .NET by using the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` modifier).

So the actual translation would be more like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+://([\\w!\"$.:@]+)(?:/(\\S*))?");
```

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have the @ string notation. So, make sure you escape all the '\' in your regexp. `(\w+ becomes> \\w+, \/ becomes> \\/, \x21 becomes> \\x21, etc. )`

Answer (score 1):

Named groups are done differently in .NET than in all the other Regex flavors. You have:

```
(?<Domain>pattern)
```

Java (and everyone else) expects:

```
(?P<Domain>pattern)
```

Comment: Java doesn't have named groups at all, yet. They're being added in Java 7.